# How to make a log log histogram in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Given an an array of values, I want to plot a log log histogram of these values by their counts. I only know how to log the x values, but not the y values because they are not explicitly created in my program.

Answer (score 28):

Check out the pyplot [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

- pyplot.hist can "log" y axis for you with keyword argument log=True
- pyplot.hist accepts `bins` keyword argument, but you have to "log" x axis yourself

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = numpy.random.gumbel(2 ** 20, 2 ** 19, (1000, ))

bins = range(15, 25)
plt.xticks(bins, ["2^%s" % i for i in bins])
plt.hist(numpy.log2(data), log=True, bins=bins)
plt.show()
```

This will give you the actual counts of how how many elements fall into each bin, plotted on a log axis (which is what people usually mean by a log plot). I couldn't tell from your wording if you wanted this or the log of the count plotted on a linear axis.

Btw., bins don't even have to be spaced evenly.

Comment: To plot the log of the count of a linear axis is comparatively easier, and anyway both methods give the same graph. +1 for the key beginning. But I don't get what you do in the code : are you displaying fake exponential tick tags on what's really a linear x-scale ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54529366/8961642) we can define this simple method:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_loghist(x, bins):
  hist, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
  logbins = np.logspace(np.log10(bins[0]),np.log10(bins[-1]),len(bins))
  plt.hist(x, bins=logbins)
  plt.xscale('log')
  plt.yscale('log')
```

And after that call like this:

```
plot_loghist(data, 10)
```

This is an example of the output for my data:
[image]