# plotting a histogram on a Log scale with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, statistics

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has the following values in a Series

```
x = [2, 1, 76, 140, 286, 267, 60, 271, 5, 13, 9, 76, 77, 6, 2, 27, 22, 1, 12, 7, 19, 81, 11, 173, 13, 7, 16, 19, 23, 197, 167, 1]
```

I was instructed to plot two histograms in a Jupyter notebook with Python 3.6.

```
x.plot.hist(bins=8)
plt.show()
```

I chose 8 bins because that looked best to me.
I have also been instructed to plot another histogram with the log of x.

```
x.plot.hist(bins=8)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

This histogram looks TERRIBLE. Am I not doing something right? I've tried fiddling around with the plot, but everything I've tried just seems to make the histogram look even worse. Example:

```
x.plot(kind='hist', logx=True)
```

I was not given any instructions other than plot the log of X as a histogram.

For the record, I have imported pandas, numpy, and matplotlib and specified that the plot should be inline.

Comment: What is "Terrible" about the histogram?

Comment: The best way/workaround is just `plt.hist(np.log(x))`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Specifying `bins=8` in the `hist` call means that the range between the minimum and maximum value is divided equally into 8 bins. What is equal on a linear scale is distorted on a log scale.

What you could do is specify the bins of the histogram such that they are unequal in width in a way that would make them look equal on a logarithmic scale.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [2, 1, 76, 140, 286, 267, 60, 271, 5, 13, 9, 76, 77, 6, 2, 27, 22, 1, 12, 7, 
     19, 81, 11, 173, 13, 7, 16, 19, 23, 197, 167, 1]
x = pd.Series(x)

# histogram on linear scale
plt.subplot(211)
hist, bins, _ = plt.hist(x, bins=8)

# histogram on log scale. 
# Use non-equal bin sizes, such that they look equal on log scale.
logbins = np.logspace(np.log10(bins[0]),np.log10(bins[-1]),len(bins))
plt.subplot(212)
plt.hist(x, bins=logbins)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `logbins = np.geomspace(x.min(), x.max(), 8)` to save typing all those logs (and bins[0], bins[-1] are just min and max anyway).

Answer (score 36):

Here is one more solution without using a subplot or plotting two things in the same image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_loghist(x, bins):
  hist, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
  logbins = np.logspace(np.log10(bins[0]),np.log10(bins[-1]),len(bins))
  plt.hist(x, bins=logbins)
  plt.xscale('log')

plot_loghist(np.random.rand(200), 10)
```

[image: example hist plot]

Comment: You should test the code before posting it - it cannot compile because of no ":" after function declaration. And, after adding it, the code still doesn't work - it only crashes.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. fixed the typo. The code works fine for me on python 3.5

Comment: Works for me too, python 3.8. Thanks for useful contribution

Answer (score 13):

> plot another histogram with the log of x.

is not the same as plotting x on the logarithmic scale. Plotting the logarithm of x would be

```
np.log(x).plot.hist(bins=8)
plt.show()
```

[image: hist]

The difference is that the values of x themselves were transformed: we are looking at their logarithm.

This is different from plotting on the logarithmic scale, where we keep x the same but change the way the horizontal axis is marked up (which squeezes the bars to the right, and stretches those to the left).

Answer (score 3):

Seaborn is also a good solution for histograms with a log scale, without having to manually specify the histogram bin edges, as you would with just matplotlib.

```
# standard imports...
import seaborn as sns

x = [2, 1, 76, 140, 286, 267, 60, 271, 5, 13, 9, 76, 77, 6, 2, 27, 22, 1, 12, 7, 19, 81, 11, 173, 13, 7, 16, 19, 23, 197, 167, 1]
x = pd.Series(x)
plt.hist(x)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.gca().set(title='Matplotlib histogram, logarithmic x axis')
plt.show()
#x.plot(kind='hist', log=True)

sns.histplot(x, bins=8, log_scale=True)
plt.gca().set(title='Seaborn histogram, logarithmic x axis')
plt.show()
sns.histplot(x, bins=8, log_scale=True)
plt.gca().set(title='Seaborn histogram, logarithmic x axis, with scalar ticks')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.gca().set_xticks([1, 10, 100, 150])
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]
[image: And another]
[image: And another]

Answer (score 1):

According to my experiment, the use of `np.histogram` might be unnecessary, since the two ends of `x` are exactly the minimum and the maximum, which needn't `np.histogram` to calculate:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_loghist(x, bins):
    logbins = np.logspace(np.log10(np.min(x)),np.log10(np.max(x)),bins+1)
    plt.hist(x, bins=logbins)
    plt.xscale('log')


plot_loghist(np.random.rand(200), 10)
```