# python histogram with log scale on both x and y axes

Tags: python, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram of a list of 48103 positive integers, ranging from 1 to over 400,000. If I use the default settings, I get the following thoroughly unhelpful plot:

[image]

The following question explains how to make the x-axis logarithmic:
[plotting a histogram on a Log scale with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850202/plotting-a-histogram-on-a-log-scale-with-matplotlib?rq=1)

But I don't think that will be enough. I need to make the y-axis logarithmic too.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the code you wrote to change the `x` scale, and then change all `x` to `y`

Comment: "I don't think that will be enough". Why not. Did you try and run into problems?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works:

````
plt.hist(data,bins=[1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()```
````