# How to transform data to a logscale that would match matplotlib 'log' axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

As this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850534 points out, `np.log(x)` is not the same as plotting `x` on a log scale.

Given (the same) array of data:

```
x = [2, 1, 76, 140, 286, 267, 60, 271, 5, 13, 9, 76, 77, 6, 2, 27, 22, 1, 12, 7, 19, 81, 11, 173, 13, 7, 16, 19, 23, 197, 167, 1]
```

Plotting the data directly has a chart like so:

```
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Using the 'log' scale looks like:

```
plt.plot(x)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Plotting `np.log(x)` does something entirely different:

```
plt.plot(np.log(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a function that rescales the array values in logspace, or would this require something like interpolation?

Comment: Don't you want `plt.yscale('log')` in the second example instead of `plt.xscale('log')`?

Comment: @samgiz well either/both would be helpful answers. The issue is not in making matplotlib scale the axis, its transforming the data itself.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion arises from how you are plotting `x`. First of all, let's call the array `y`, since it's y-values:

```
y = [2, 1, 76, 140, 286, 267, 60, 271, 5, 13, 9, 76, 77, 6, 2, 27, 22, 1, 12, 7, 19, 81, 11, 173, 13, 7, 16, 19, 23, 197, 167, 1]
```

`plt.plot(y)` is equivalent to

```
x = np.arange(len(y))
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Hopefully you can see where this is going. If you want to log-scale the x-axis, you can log-scale the values in `x`. Similarly for the y-values, or even both directions at once:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, constrained_layout=True)

ax[0, 0].semilogx(x, y)
ax[1, 0].plot(np.log(x), y)
ax[0, 1].semilogy(x, y)
ax[1, 1].plot(x, np.log(y))
ax[0, 2].loglog(x, y)
ax[1, 2].plot(np.log(x), np.log(y))

ax[0, 0].set_ylabel('Scaled Axes')
ax[1, 0].set_ylabel('Scaled Data')
ax[0, 0].set_title('X')
ax[0, 1].set_title('Y')
ax[0, 2].set_title('Both')
```

[image]

Comment: okay thanks. I this was kind of doing the same thing I wanted to get around; using matplotlib to scale the data. I can call it x or y, its a single array of data that should correspond to 'equal' spacing (where equal is either linear or... log). So making a new log of linear x data points that matplotlib does the conversion for me doesn't solve it.  I was looking for a mapping e.g., for each point in the series, what would the new y value be in log space.

Comment: * I still think this answer is really helpful though, and to others

Comment: @001001. I literally answered your question. The logarithm is exactly how you map to log space. There is no catch here.

Comment: Sorry if I am not explaining well, or if I am missing the obvious next step to get the array. What I am trying to say is, the reason I was plotting only 'x' was because the data is some array of evenly spaced y values, so there is no need to set a custom 'x' labels with 'y' values. meaning, `plt.plot(x)` will use the indices as the 'step' in x, with the value as the 'y' axis.  I want to transform the data of the array, so that `plt.plot(x')` plots to be the same graph as if I was to use the log axis scale, whereas (as I understand) your answer uses a secondary array to map?

Comment: @001001. Whether you pass it in or not, the x-axis is going to be `np.arange(len(y))`. If you want to log scale the x-position, you have to map *that* array to log space, not `y`.

Answer (score -2):

Even though your variable is named `x`, when you plot it, it is plotted as the y-coordinate. Try doing `plt.yscale('log')`